# How can I set a boolean attribute dynamically in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

First attempt:

```
<button type="submit" class="button" {{#if isDirty(item)}}disabled{{/if}}>Save2</button>
```

causes an error during compile:

```
bundling...
   (svelte plugin) Error: (28:75) Expected >
26:         <div class="row">
27:           <!-- FIXME Can't set an attribute dynamically? -->
28:           <button type="submit" class="button" {{#if isDirty(item)}}disabled{{/if}}>Save2</button>
                                                                               ^
```

The best I could come up with:

```
{{#if isDirty(item)}}
  <button type="submit" class="button" disabled>Save</button>
{{else}}
  <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Svelte 'fixes' HTML so that the `disabled` attribute (and other boolean attributes) behave more sanely:

```js
<button type="submit" class="button" disabled='{isDirty(item)}'>Save</button>
```

[Demo here.](https://svelte.dev/repl/ef97160409ee419fb4858c527f0a1848?version=3.23.0)

EDIT: Updated example and Demo to Svelte 3

Comment: It is important that the `isDirty(item)` function only works if called with a parameter which is bound. In the example (and demo) above, that variable is `item`. So, simple a function like `isDirty()` wouldn't work.